# Debugger not stopping at breakpoints in VS-Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have just installed VS Code and the Python extension, and I have not been able to get the debugger to work. Every time I try to use the debugger, it just skips over any breakpoints that I have set and runs the program like normal.

I am using VS Code on a Windows 10 PC with Python 3.7.3 and the Python extension installed. I followed the instructions here (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) to make a test folder called 'hello' in C:\python_work\hello and create a program called 'hello.py' inside that folder. hello.py is shown below. I tried using the debugger both by pressing the green arrow and by pressing F5, but neither seemed to make the debugger work properly. My 'launch.json' file is also shown below.

hello.py:

```py
msg = "Hello World!"
print(msg) # Breakpoint
```

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": true
        },
    ]
}
```

I expected the bottom bar to turn orange and the program to stop on the second line, allowing me to examine the local and global variables in the preview pane. Instead, the bottom bar stayed orange for 1/2 a second while the program ran as if I had pressed "Run Python File in Terminal," without stopping at the breakpoint. Please help!

Comment: It's working fine for me. What is being sent to the terminal to launch the debugger?

Comment: Something like this:

`cd c:\python_work\hello && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && C:\Python\python.exe c:\Users\RohanPC\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.22090\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 49389 c:\python_work\hello\hello.py "`

Comment: If you could file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python and provide a GitHub project or zipfile of a folder that can reproduce the problem then we can have a look and see if we can figure out what's going on.

Comment: I just reinstalled Windows and the problem got solved! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It's generally regarded as good practice to reinstall Windows at least twice a day.

Comment: On MacOS, "run->start debugging (F5)"  sometimes does not stop at breakpoints. Assuming the Python module is run as a a script  (ie, it contains a condition `if __name__ == "__main__": `), and in case a Python exception is hit during execution, then VS Code breaks with a pop-up message "Exception has occurred: System Exit" in the main section. At this point, click "run->restart debugging (shift-cmd-F5)" and voila': now breakpoints are hit.

Answer (score 94):

Setting `"justMyCode": false` makes it stop at breakpoint:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Debug Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "justMyCode": false
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: this worked... how am I supposed to guess something like this?

Comment: weird that it's not "true" by default ! Another problem I'm facing now is, it doesn't end the debugging after execution of the last line. it goes into "runpy.py"... how should I fix this one?

Comment: Without resources like StackOverflow I don't think I'd ever have solved this.  Just My Code is a set of features that makes it easier to focus on debugging your code by hiding some of the details of optimized libraries that you might be using, like the .NET Framework itself (says https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#just-my-code).  But I'm running a program I wrote which contains a few simple lines, and no calls to any modules.  Can anyone throw any light on why I need to turn this feature off?

Comment: How do I find this file to make this edit?

Comment: On menu bar , click Run and then Open Configuration

Comment: Yes, but it should work with this set to "true". justMyCode makes sure that Step In, etc go into your own code only, and not the code of the library you're importing.

Comment: Clearly a bug in "justMyCode".

Comment: true, seems like a bug, logically

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Strangely, `stopOnEntry: true` does make the debugger stop at the start of the application, but all  breakpoints further on are ignored.

Comment: In my case, I had to set `django: true` too, because well… it's a django app.

Comment: if you have cloned a repo, the code from the repo is not seen as your code. Ergo, you will have to set `justMyCode` to `false`

Answer (score 52):

If you're using a `pytest-cov` module you might also wanna have a look at [pytest configuration settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_pytest-configuration-settings) note:

> **Note** If you have the `pytest-cov` coverage module installed, VS Code doesn't stop at breakpoints while debugging because `pytest-cov` is using the same technique to access the source code being run. To prevent this behavior, include `--no-cov` in `pytestArgs` when debugging tests, for example by adding `"env": {"PYTEST_ADDOPTS": "--no-cov"}` to your debug configuration.

See an example configuration file (`launch.json`) below:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "test",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "env": {"PYTEST_ADDOPTS": "--no-cov"}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem I was facing too. I had this in my .vscode/settings.json:

{
  "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
    "--cov=src",
    "--cov-report",
    "html",
    "tests"
  ]   // Removing the coverage related lines solved the problem.

Comment: In my case, coverage was setup in my `setup.cfg` file. It worked by either removing it from that file or using Tomasz's `"env"` tip. Thank you!

Comment: VSCode highlights the line 'request': 'test' with a warning:


`Request type of configuration. Can be "launch" or "attach".
Value is not accepted. Valid values: "launch".`

but it works anyway.

Comment: This has recently changed: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests. Need to add  `"purpose": ["debug-test"]`. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_purpose

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same behaviour and was able to solve it by installing the virtual environment of Python in the following way:

```
[MyProjectFolder] \ venv
```

by entering the command

```
python -m venv [MyProjectFolder]\venv
```

in the console.

VS Code seems to expect exactly that folder structure.

Before I had installed the venv-folder-structure directly in my projects-folder, i.e.

```
[MyProjectFolder] \ Scripts
[MyProjectFolder] \ Lib
[MyProjectFolder] \ Include
[MyProjectFolder] \ pyvenv.cfg
```

which **did not work** and caused exactly the described debug problems.

just as a reference: VS Code version 1.52.1 and Python 3.8.5

Comment: This creates a .venv but doesn't allow me to select a venv interpreter

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the debug point issue. You can select the Python interpreter doing `CTRL+Shift+P` -> `Select Python Interpreter` -> `Enter interpreter path`

Comment: Thanks for this answer, the scripts lib include and pyenv.cfg should be removed before running the python -m venv command, install new venv format then restart vscode

Comment: That did the trick for me!

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading from Python 3.9 to 3.8 worked for me.

VC Code 1.56.2 ignored breakpoints running Python 3.9 64-bit on Windows 10 version 20H2.  Installing Python 3.8.10 64-bit fixed the problem.  I just needed to select the Python 3.8.10 interpreter within VS code and it now recognizes breakpoints.  No changes to the configuration file were needed, for example, I did not need "justMyCode": false

I realize this is an old question, but my google search lead me to it.  Many of the previous answers no longer apply. So I'm posting this fix for others who land here in 2021 trying to use 3.9.

Comment: I'm on Python 3.8.2 and debug points never worked for me.

Comment: I also tried downgrading further: I went from Python 3.8.2 x64 to Python 3.7.8 x32 and debug points still do not work.

Comment: Also tried downgrading from 3.9 to 3.8, but still not working. If someone found a fix, please share!

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that I was putting the breakpoint on the line of the function declaration itself, so the `def foo(x):` line, instead of putting the breakpoint on the first *non-comment* line *inside* of the function.

If the first line of your function is a comment, the debugger will assume you meant to place the breakpoint on the line of the function declaration and move your breakpoint back, so really make sure you aren't placing your breakpoint on a comment!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem having upgraded from Python version 3.7 to version 3.9. I later found out that the old version was 32 bit, and the new version I upgraded to was 64 bit, which apparently caused the issues. Uninstalling the 64 bit version and installing the 32 bit version of Python 3.9 solved my problem, and I was then able to use the Visual Studio Code breakpoint functionality again.

Comment: This did not work for me. Went from Python 3.8.2 x64 to Python 3.7.8 x32 and debug points still do not work.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone coming here looking for a solution related to breakpoints in python unittests:

1. If not already done add a configuration file, i.e. `launch.json`, as described in the [vscode python debugging tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_configure-and-run-the-debugger).
2. For me the following configuration settings worked, whereby setting `cwd` (because of  `src` and `test` folders) and `purpose` (see also [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17644)) were essential.

```json
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Test Cases",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/afinad/src",
            "purpose": [
                "debug-test"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
        }
    ]
```

Happy debugging!

Comment: It's `launch.json`, not `lunch.json`  lol

Comment: @JeffWright: In some sense it might be also the latter ;), however, thanks for pointing that out, it is corrected now

Answer (score 1):

Another source of no-breakpoints-working is `elevate`:

```
try: # https://pypi.org/project/elevate/
    from elevate import elevate
except ModuleNotFoundError: # install it if not found
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", 'elevate'])
finally:
    from elevate import elevate

# require elevated permissions right away...
elevate()
```

The `elevate()` command restarts the program as a new (child) process, so the entire file becomes un-breakpoint-able.  From the author:

> On Windows, the new process’s standard streams are not attached to the parent, which is an inherent limitation of UAC.

In windows, to debug python applications in VS Code which need to be run as administrator, a work-around is this:

1. Close VS Code.
2. Right-click VS Code icon, choose "Run as Administrator."

Linux users could likely do the same with `sudo code`.  Now the process will be spawned initially as administrator, so the call to `elevate()` does nothing and the whole file is debuggable.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found out ( 5th May 2020) that using Python 3.9 as interpreter the breakpoints were not hitting. Install 3.8 and it will start working again.

Comment: I'm on Python 3.8.2 and debug points never worked for me.

Comment: I also tried downgrading further: I went from Python 3.8.2 x64 to Python 3.7.8 x32 and debug points still do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Another source of debugger not stopping at breakpoint: an homonym file,  from another directory, is open in VS Code.

In fact, VS Code can set breakpoints on any Python file, even outside of your Python project's directory; if the path of the file does not match the one in launch.json, `"program": [your-file-name-here]` entry, then breakpoints are not hit.

For example: copies of Python source files are located under dist/lib, the output of [setuptools](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/) (run: `python setup.py bdist_wheel` to generate them).

If `dist/lib` is not excluded through `.gitignore`, then its contents shows up in the search results sidebar and can be click open by mistake.

Caveat: the above does not hold if the launch.json configuration has `"program": "${file}"`.

Answer (score 0):

I (re)downloaded VS Code again: https://code.visualstudio.com/
The breakpoint got to show up on hover and function with the `Run and Debug` for the python file I was working on.

Additionally, I had to solve a syntax error in my code before the debugger buttons (step over/in, etc) had to go through the code lines

Answer (score 0):

I have been battling with this for the last hour, and it finally worked by renaming my python file from camelCase.py to snake_case.py

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as I was walking through this [VSCode tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_prerequisites).

My debugger did not work because I accidentally put the file in the `.venv` folder.  When I moved it out of there it ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

Weighing in late here but I'm not sure the version of Python is part of the issue. I think the real issue is with the 32 bit versus 64 bit versions of Python. I am on Python 3.10.11 and changed my interpreter from 64 bit to 32 bit and the debugger started hit the breakponts.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I had to do the following.  I don't know which item(s) below solved the issue, but hopefully this will be helpful to someone.  The Python debugger I was using was called *Python File*, as opposed to the other two optional Python debuggers, *Python File with Arguments* and *Module*.

1.) Deleted the file "pyvenv.cfg" in the working folder.  It contained the contents.  This got created automatically somehow from earlier debugger sessions.

```
home = C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0
include-system-site-packages = true
version = 3.7.9
```

2.) The first time I created the virtual environment in GitBash with the Python File debugger not working was the following:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0"
python3 -m venv --system-site-packages "C:\Python\source"
```

3.) The second time I created the virtual environment in GitBash, I added a new folder in my source directory (path of my Python file being debugged) called venv.

```
cd "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0"
python -m venv --system-site-packages "C:\Python\source\venv"
```