# Python in VS Code: Not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a simple Python program that reads a CSV and writes a new one in VS Code. When I set a breakpoint, it gets skipped. I am able to use `breakpoint()` and get the basic Python debugger, but I'd prefer to be able to use the VS Code debugger. I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794940/debugger-not-stopping-at-breakpoints-in-vs-code-for-python) and [this documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging), but neither resolved the issue. I am on Windows, Python version 3.9.1. I am not an experienced Python developer, so it's very possible I'm missing something obvious, but I have done my fair share of .NET development.

**UPDATE 1: launch.json and code**

```
launch.json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

For the code, I've set breakpoints all over the place trying to get it to work, but here is my `main.py`. I've tried a breakpoint on the line `h.get_approvers()`:

```
import adp
import hierarchy
import expensify
import sys

h = hierarchy.Hierarchy()
h.get_approvers()
```

**UPDATE 2: Terminal output when debugging**

```
Loading personal and system profiles took 664ms.
PS C:\Users\...\OneDrive - ZoomInfo\Dev\Sandbox\PyTest> & C:/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/.../OneDrive - ZoomInfo/Dev/Sandbox/PyTest/main.py"        
Hello world
PS C:\Users\...\OneDrive - ZoomInfo\Dev\Sandbox\PyTest>
```

Comment: I personally have not had issue with VSCode on my MacOS.  Have you had a gander at the official docs https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging?

Comment: Any useful errors in `TERMINAL` or `PROBLEMS` pane?

Comment: @RazzleShazl I followed the Python-specific instructions in the official docs for setting up the debugger. That's my second link above. No errors in Terminal or Problems pane.

Comment: I'm out of ideas.  If it's any help, here is my `launch.json` https://pastebin.com/RAtkYMFJ

Comment: Please post your launch.json, a sample/portion of your code, and which line exactly did you place a breakpoint. Without these things, this is just guesswork.

Comment: start debugging with a simple "Hello World" program. Read the Python docs of VSC, not only the debugger docs

Comment: @Mike Caputo -Have you installed the [python extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_install-visual-studio-code-and-the-python-extension) in VS Code? In VS Code, Python's debugging function is provided by the Python extension. If it is installed, please try to reinstall it and reload VS Code.

Comment: @GinoMempin posted

Comment: @JillCheng yes, I have the Python extension installed. I just removed and re-added it, and breakpoints still don't work.

Comment: @rioV8 I did read the Python VS Code docs.

Comment: @Mike Caputo -Can it stop at a breakpoint when you use other code? I tested the code you provided, and there is a problem at the code "h = hierarchy.Hierarchy()", so it will exit this debugging.

Comment: @JillCheng I just did a totally new project, added print("Hello world"), set a breakpoint on  that line, and it skipped it.

Comment: @Mike Caputo  -Have you tested whether python is available? Please enter "python" in cmd outside VS Code to check whether it can enter the python interactive window.

Comment: @JillCheng that worked.

Comment: @Mike Caputo -How do you debug the code? Could you please provide us with a screenshot of debugging "print("Hello world")" and the information displayed on the VS Code terminal? (Please overwrite the personal information such as the user name in the screenshot.)

Comment: @JillCheng I don't have enough reputation to post an image, unfortunately. However, I have posted the text of the terminal output above.

Comment: Set the breakpoint and run the python program from terminal? I got this sometime. When I run the program from terminal, the debugging worked. This is just a workaround. If that works, check the configuration again.

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida I just tried running from terminal and the breakpoint did not catch.

Comment: As I can see in the update 2, the program is returning hello world. That means some other program is running. Not the one you are trying to debug. Do you have any files other than this one? Are you trying to refer that other program in here?

Comment: If you are working in a virtual environment you need to switch to the venv interpreter.  Not a fan of this not working out of the box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**
The issue has been closed and I have received confirmation that it was related to the `Python version 3.9.3 (64 bit)`.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15865

**Original Post**

This has been driving me nuts and needs further investigation, but what I noticed

`Python 3.9.3 64 bit` >> skips breakpoints
and
`Python 3.9.2 64 bit` >> works as expected

I have reproduced this multiple times just to ensure that I wasn't just solving a problem with a simple un-/reinstall.

I have raised an issue for this and I'll update this reply as soon as I find the proper root cause, but for now this solves the problem at my end...although not to my satisfaction.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15865

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in the terminal information you provided, the only paths used are "python.exe" and the file "main.py" path.

In VS Code, the debugging function of Python code is provided by Python extensions. Therefore, when debugging python scripts, it will use "python interpreter" (`python.exe`), "python extension" (`.vscode\extensions\ms -python.python-2021.1.502429796\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy`), and "python script" (`.py file`).

When I click the green run button in the upper right corner of VS Code, the path displayed on the VS Code terminal is only `python.exe` and the `".py" file`: Run the code and it will not stay at the breakpoint.

[image]

When I click `F5` or the "`Start Debugging`" button: Debug code it will stay at the breakpoint.

[image]

If it still doesn't work, please try to reinstall the Python extension and reload VS Code.

Reference: [Python debugging in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging).

Comment: first of all, I just want to say thanks for all the time you're putting into this. I really appreciate your help. To respond to your answer, I discovered that the Start Debugging thing (as opposed to the green Run button) works as well; the only problem with it is it doesn't actually use breakpoints. It just stops at the first line always. So I can use it for now, but if I want to set a breakpoint in the middle of my code, I can't. Also, I did already try reinstalling the Python extension and reloading VS Code.

Comment: @Mike Caputo  -This is strange. Have you installed and used other VS Code extensions? Please try to disable them to avoid their influence on the debugging function of python extension.

Comment: Reinstalling worked for me! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 with Python 3.11 this is still a problem with any code but yours (!) (defined by  default `justMyCode` setting).

Solution is to add to your launch.json a separate configuration:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
            "name": "Debug Python",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "program": "${file}",
        },
... [rest of your file]
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was wrong setting of environment variables.
I had a `PYTHON_DIR` pointing to python 3.7, `PYTHON_DIR` vas used also in Path variable and `PYTHON_HOME` pointing to python 3.6

Running file worked well but debugging didn't provide any output in Terminal pane and didn't stop on breakpoint.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).