# Debugger does not stop on breakpoints (python. VS code)

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

This is running Visual Studio Code (version 1.55.0 user setup) on Windows 10, with python 3.9.

Whenever I try to add breakpoints to my python files, it marks it in the GUI as a breakpoint (red circle), but when I try to debug it goes right over them as if I never included them at all.
As a test I created an empty folder with only a short python test file, and the debugger went right over the breakpoints.

For context here is the brief test file (I made every line a breakpoint):

```
print('test')
print('test2')
foo = 1+2
print(foo)
```

I tried initially to use the default debug configuration (by clicking run -> start debugging -> python file). When that didn't work I thought that maybe the default was having an issue, but even manually creating the json file did not fix it.

Json file for context:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

This seems similar to a question posed here: [Debugger Not Stopping at Breakpoints in VS Code for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794940/debugger-not-stopping-at-breakpoints-in-vs-code-for-python;) however, either my issue is caused by something else, or that information is outdated, because neither the solution of adding `"justMyCode": false` to the json file; nor just re-installing everything, fix anything.

Comment: some python code with `if` statements do not generate bytecode so no possibility to break on these lines, if you don't post the problem code we can't investigate,

Comment: @rioV8
The problem code is posted. It's the test file code. I don't know how to do the fancy code styling in comments (where it gets dark), but it's the: "print('test')
print('test2')
foo = 1+2
print(foo)" code that's listed in the question above.

My project code isn't needed because the issue is still present on the test sample so it's not an issue with that, it's an issue with the something meta about visual studio code

Comment: @Slam9 -Which VS Code extensions did you use? Where is the location of the "launch.json" for configuration debugging you are using? (Whether it is in the ".vscode" of the currently opened project.) In addition, since the debugging function of python is provided by the 'Python' extension, please try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

A newbie reason why you are not stopping on breakpoints (especially if you are not used to VSCode):

If you run the code using the green arrow icon, the breakpoints will not be hit. You will be able to set breakpoints and see the red dot next to the line, but the debugger will not stop on any of them.

If you start execution with F5, *then* the debugger will stop on the breakpoint(s).

The green arrow icon is "Run Python in terminal" which ignores breakpoints, while F5 is "Continue" which invokes the debugger.

Comment: I thought ctrl+f5 ran the debugger...I had it backwards

Answer (score 0):

Are you using python 3.9.3? I had the same issue, but it is related to python version and was fixed on 3.9.4.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15865