# Why is VSCode not stopping at breakpoints for debugging?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

So, I know there is this previous posting about this: [Debugger Not Stopping at Breakpoints in VS Code for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794940/debugger-not-stopping-at-breakpoints-in-vs-code-for-python)

However, I'm having the exact same issue on a newer version of VSCode.

My setup:

- Manjaro Linux
- Official MS VSCode (1.55.2)
- Python Extension added, and mostly at defaults (below are my settings.json settings related to python)

  ```
  "[python]": {
      "editor.detectIndentation": true,
      "editor.insertSpaces": true
  },
  "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
  "python.linting.flake8Args": [
      "--ignore=F401,F841,E501,E305,E302"
  ],
  "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
  "python.venvPath": "/home/greg/git/code/python/venvs"
  ```
- Here are my launch.json settings:

  ```
  {
      // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
      // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
      // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
          {
              "name": "Python: Debug Current File",
              "type": "python",
              "request": "launch",
              "program": "${file}",
              "console": "integratedTerminal",
              "stopOnEntry": true,
              "justMyCode": false
          }
      ]
  }
  ```

Comment: there is python code that does NOT generate Python VM instructions, they are optimized away, without code that has the artifact we can't help, disassemble the smallest code with the problem

Comment: I even just put a simple 'print("Hello World")', still gives me the same problem

Comment: Please try [VSCode Insider](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

1. Remove the `launch.json` from the project (save it somewhere else in case you need it)
2. Restart VS Code
3. Try debugging. If it prompts you for a `launch.json`, just go with the defaults.

Comment: After trying several recommendations this one worked!  Thanks