# Vs Code skips Breakpoints after "import"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When debugging my code, my breakpoints are ignored by visual studio code, once I use these lines of code:

```
from brainflow.board_shim import BoardShim, BrainFlowInputParams, BoardIds
from brainflow.data_filter import DataFilter, FilterTypes, DetrendOperations, AggOperations
```

No error Message is given.
I edited my launch.json in accordance to this post: [Debugger Not Stopping at Breakpoints in VS Code for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794940/debugger-not-stopping-at-breakpoints-in-vs-code-for-python)

And tried several others, but nothing solves my issue.
Probably my import is wrong/has an error? (if anybody knows something brainflow specific, please let me know. First time using it so.. yeah...)

Here my Minimal Code example:

```
#Bt_Connection
#python -m pip install brainflow
#pip install pybluez
#python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

import argparse
import time
import socket
import os

from brainflow.board_shim import BoardShim, BrainFlowInputParams, BoardIds
from brainflow.data_filter import DataFilter, FilterTypes, DetrendOperations, AggOperations

msg="X"
print(msg)

test= "test"
print(test)
```

And some screenshots since the error really only becomes visible in the IDE. (Video would be better, but you have to believe me that the breakpoints are not hit.)
[image]

[image]

In the second picture the code only stops at the first line, since that is specified in my launch.json. But once I hit continue it just goes through the code without stoping and writes "X" and "test" in the terminal.

launch.json for completions sake:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Debug Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Python Version: 3.11.2 64 bit

And for Visual Studio Code:

[image]

Comment: This has something to do with the python version. I used python 3.11 and python 3.10 for testing, and found the same problem with python 3.11, but with python 3.10
No problem.

Comment: True, I installed Python 3.10.10 and it works just fine... Thanks that really solves my issue for now.
 Off topic: that feels like a (maybe major) error on pythons part here. Or is there any reason to this? seems at least less user friendly.

Comment: Thanks, done so. If you find my question sufficiently well, please consider hitting the upvote, so more people can find it. ( I have seen a few threads with similar issues, but never this solution, so i guess this would be a good thing for others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with your python version. Using **the python 3.10** version you will get the desired effect.

Report it on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/1284