# Debugger in Python is running like in no debug mode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

I am coding in VS code with Python and I have Python extension installed. I put breakpoints anywhere in my program (I am sure the code works) and when I launch my program in debugging mode (F5 or start debugging) it runs just like in no debugging mode. Maybe any ideas what can cause this?

Simplest code I try to run:

```
import pandas as pd

tsv_file = 'historicalData.tsv'
df = pd.read_table(tsv_file)
```

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60678160/17200348)?

Comment: could you also share where you added the breakpoints in the above example?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of "JustMyCode" in `launch.json` is true. This means debugger will debug only user-written codes.

You can add `"justMyCode": false` to your `launch.json` to change it.