# Debugger not stopping at breakpoints in VSCode (python code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

When I run python in 1.84.2 vscode, I found that breakpoints did not work. It didn't stop where I interrupted, but stopped where thre was not breakpoint. This problem makes me very anxisous. I can't find a solution to the problem, and if I can't solve it, I would give up vscode, but I don't want to do this. Please help me.

The problem is as shown in:
[image]

launch.json file

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true,
        
    }
```

I don't know where the porblem is, I didn't have any problem before, but this problem occurred when I used it two months later. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: tf belongs to the package you imported, and only your code will be debugged according to your `launch.json`, so it will skip this breakpoint. You have to change `"justMyCode": true,` to false.

Comment: I tried it but the problem is still not solved. In addtion, I also made several attempts, such as installing an older version of vscode, add ""purpose":["debug-in-terminal"]" in setting file and restarting vscode, but it still didn't work. And I found some problem: when running other files, the problem of invalid breakpoints will not occur, even if justMyCode set to true, and sometimes breakpoints work, but it is invalid when running again. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Is there any error report when debugging? I see that your python doesn't provide intellisense correctly, a possible conjecture that you didn't choose the python environment correctly.

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Please also add the version of your Python extension.

Comment: There is no error, it just does not stop where there is a breakpoint, but stops where there is no breakpoint. How to choose the python environment correctly? You mean installing python plugins in extensions?

Comment: One possible solution is to click on ·Run and Debug· in the left-hand menu, then debug by clicking on the triangle run symbol(The same as shortcuts **F5**).

Comment: I tried it but it still doesn't work. I usually click Run-Start Debugging in the upper-left corner menu to debug code. Thank you very much for your patient guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your setting "justMyCode" to false for breakpoints to work in vscode.

More can be read [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794940/debugger-not-stopping-at-breakpoints-in-vs-code?rq=2)

Comment: I tried it but the problem is still not solved. In addtion, I also made several attempts, such as installing an older version of vscode, add ""purpose":["debug-in-terminal"]" in setting file and restarting vscode, but it still didn't work. And I found some problem: when running other files, the problem of invalid breakpoints will not occur, even if justMyCode set to true, and sometimes breakpoints work, but it is invalid when running again. What is the reason for this?